# Cluster data into good and bad

Tags: cluster-analysis, hierarchical-clustering

I need to divide data points into those that are similar to each other("good" points) and everyone else("bad" points).

It looks like some kind of clustering problem and what do I do:

I am assuming that there are at least two "good" points.

1. Find pairwise distance between all types of points.
2. Find minimum distance (minDist).
3. Do hierarchical clustering for all points.
4. Make a cut at the height of 5*minDist.
5. Say that all points that are in the same cluster as pair with minDist and under that cut belong to the desired "good" cluster.

And this works pretty well, but if there are two points that are very close to each other. minDist is very small and this 5*minDist cut is also small => only these 2 points are in the desired "good" cluster.

I would think that either I need to change this approach completely and here is question number 1:

[1] "What methods do exist to separate similar points from everyone else?"

Or I need to modify this 5*minDist to some other function of minDist. And question is:

[2] "What may I choose as reasonable alternative to 5*minDist?"

Vladimir

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing clustering, you want to do *outlier detection*.

There are dozens of algorithms for this (see ELKI for a large collection). Some very basic methods may solve your problem:

1. The number of neighbors in radius r. If +i < threshold, the point is an outlier.
2. Distance to the k nearest neighbor. Choose k>1 to avoid these 2 element clusters you are seeing.

Also, DBSCAN clustering could work for you. Consider *all* clusters to be good, and only *noise* to be bad!